# Divs beside and among each other

Tags: css, html

It's hard to explain what my problem is, I tried to google it and search for the problem here. I can't find anyone how has the same problem. I want my divs arranged like Google Keeps notepads. All divs should be among and beside each other, no space between only the margin. To understand what I mean, I posted an image in my JSFiddle (I don't have the right to post images here).

```
.col {
    display: inline;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

<div class="col">Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content...</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5t6tm/14/

Comment: think you'll have to use a bit of js for that.  [this is a good plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: yeah, I think without js it won't work.

Comment: why dont you use `float:left;` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
.col {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 5px;
vertical-align: top;
float: left;
}



    <div class="col">Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content... Some content... Some content... Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content... Some content... Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content... Some content... Some content...</div>
<div class="col">Some content... Some content... Some content...</div>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block;` should work. Just be careful of whitespace in your html when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to achieve this without javascript in the past.

You may want to have a look at Masonry, it's a jquery plugin that does pretty much exactly what you're asking for.

http://masonry.desandro.com

Alternatively, you might consider having a number of columns of divs, each with an explicit width and floated left or right?

```
.column {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

<div class="column">
    <div class"item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class"item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class"item">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class"item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class"item">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

This might be an acceptable solution, although it will impact your semantics and perhaps responsiveness.

Comment: I have to solve this with js. The solution from GeenHenk won't work for me